# How to `reframe` all the columns in a dataframe?

Tags: r, dplyr

Hello I would like to reframe all the columns in a tibble that contains all list columns without having to specify all the columns by name. Below contains an example. my_data is all list columns and I want to turn it into a regular dataframe using `reframe`. I can do this by specifying all the names of the columns.

```
library(dplyr)
my_data <- tibble(C1 = list(c(1,2,3,4)),
       C2 = list(c(5,6,7,8)),
       C3 = list(c(9,10,11,12)))

my_data |> 
  rowwise() |> 
  reframe(C1, C2, C3) #The output I would like to get
#> # A tibble: 4 × 3
#>      C1    C2    C3
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     5     9
#> 2     2     6    10
#> 3     3     7    11
#> 4     4     8    12

my_data |> 
  rowwise() |> 
  reframe(everything()) #Would like to find a way to reframe all the columns
#> Error in `reframe()`:
#> ℹ In argument: `everything()`.
#> ℹ In row 1.
#> Caused by error:
#> ! `everything()` must be used within a *selecting* function.
#> ℹ See <https://tidyselect.r-lib.org/reference/faq-selection-context.html> for
#>   details.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you can probably do this using unnest() from tidyverse to flatten the list columns into a regular dataframe. You can use unnest() with everything() to unnest all columns:

```
library(tidyverse)

my_data <- tibble(C1 = list(c(1,2,3,4)),
                  C2 = list(c(5,6,7,8)),
                  C3 = list(c(9,10,11,12)))

my_data %>%
  unnest(everything())
```

This function will return a new dataframe where all the list columns have been unnested. You can use it on any dataframe with list columns without having to specify each column by name. The `unnest(everything())` line of code is unnesting all columns.

Comment: I would not redefine the `reframe` function, but using `unnest()` works.

Comment: @neilfws, I see, yes, I agree! I thought OP would like to define a function called "reframe". I just modified my codes :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `dplyr::reframe` you could use `tidyr::unnest_longer` like so:

```r
library(tidyr)

my_data |>
  tidyr::unnest_longer(everything())
#> # A tibble: 4 × 3
#>      C1    C2    C3
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     5     9
#> 2     2     6    10
#> 3     3     7    11
#> 4     4     8    12
```

Comment: This returns error "unused argument (cols = everything())", but just using `unnest()` works.

Comment: @neilfws Interesting. Runs fine when I run it via the `reprex` package. Perhaps a package version issue? I'm using tidyr ‘1.3.0’.

Comment: My error! I used the argument `cols = everything()`. `col = everything()` (with no 's') works fine, so does `everything()`.